# React prevent global styles from impacting component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In a React app, while there are ways like using "styled-components" so that the styles defined inside that component using "styled-components" do not have any effect on the outside world.
However, I believe that the reverse can still have an impact i.e. outside global styles like say Bootstrap CSS can affect elements inside our component.

Is that true and are there ways to prevent global styles from impacting us ? Or that is something which is CSS construct and we cannot really prevent ?

Comment: Yes, that's the "cascading" part of CSS.  You'll have to narrow your CSS selectors if you don't want it to do that.  As for Bootstrap reaching in and affecting your components, it's intended to be a sort of base-line that you build on top of.  If you don't want that, you can consider using a [custom build](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/) that would exclude those pieces that are affecting your product.

Answer (score 0):

Actually It's something relative to css struct, it's like a inherited tree.

when you style a div, all divs even if they have other classNames are affected by styles applyed to div.

And when when you styled specific class, or id (or when you have "styled-components") in react, it only affect itslef without affect all divs or other classes.

i Don't think you can  prevent global styles from impacting divs, but you can override it.

the more you are specify in classnames the more you prevent global styles from impacting us